# My inner-join isn't working

Tags: hibernate, inner-join, entities

I made a inner-join between two tables, but it isn't working.
It would help me a lot, if someone could help me as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance

It looks like this:

```
List<Bondetal> bondetals = session.createQuery("from Bondetal bd inner join bd.Bon b where bd.idbon = b.idbon and idprodus = " + idprodus +" and Bon.suma >=" + suma).list();
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Bon of: sakila.entity.Bondetal [from sakila.entity.Bondetal bd inner join bd.Bon b where bd.idbon = b.idbon and idprodus = 2 and Bon.suma >=1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to make a join, you need an association between the entities. The BonDetal entity should thus have something like

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idbon")
private Bon bon;
```

It must not have any `idbon` property, since the idbon column is mapped by the association.

And the query doesn't need any `where bd.idbon = b.idbon` clause, since Hibernate knows how the entities are associated with each other. The query should thus be:

```
select bd from Bondetal bd 
inner join bd.bon b 
where bd.idprodus = :idprodus 
and b.suma >= :suma
```

You also should use named parameters rather than concatenating values to the query, to avoid SQL injection attacks and escaping problems.

All of this is explained in the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql). If you're in such a hurry, you should read it instead of trying random queries.

Comment: It works. You helped me a lot! and I really appreciate it. :) I tried to read from that documentation, but I didn't understand very good from there. Anyway you're my hero!!